# Set Variable to FileName on Import

Tags: excel, sas

I am using the below code to import multiple .XLSX files from a folder at once. It works great, except I am not able to distinguish between each file once it has been imported and merged. Each Excel file is data for a specific year and I need to know the year for my analysis.

Is there any way to create a variable on each import that is equal to the file name so I can distinguish between the files once they are merged?

I have done this the long way, by importing each file individually and creating a variable in each data set before the merge, but I looking for a  quicker way to accomplish this.

```
filename indata pipe 'dir X:\"Projects"\"Source Data" /b ';
/* put all the .xlsx file names in dataset file_list */
data file_list;
length fname $200 in_name out_name $200;
infile indata truncover;
input fname $ 200.;
in_name=translate(scan(fname,1,'.'),'_','-');
   out_name=cats('_',in_name);                                                                                                       
run;
data _null_;
  set file_list end=last;
  call symputx(cats('dsn',_n_),in_name);
  call symputx(cats('outdsn',_n_),out_name);
  if last then call symputx('n',_n_);
run;
%macro test;

   %do i=1 %to &n;
   PROC IMPORT OUT= work.&&outdsn&i.
            DATAFILE= "X:\Projects\Source Data\&&dsn&i...xlsx"
            DBMS=XLSX REPLACE;
  Range="FundingByYear$A3:J5249";
     GETNAMES=YES;
     MIXED=NO;

RUN;

%end;
%mend;
%test

data final;
  set _:;
run;
```

Comment: Perhaps the SET statement option INDSNAME=variable would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the name of the source DATASET using the INDSNAME option on the SET statement.

```
data final;
  length dsname temp_dsname $41 ;
  set _: indsname=temp_dsname;
  dsname=temp_dsname;
run;
```

You could then use that to merge with your FILE_LIST dataset if your wanted information on the source file.